# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when coding in python

Tags: python

The code that I have is

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> with open('example.txt') as f:
        print Counter(letter for line in f 
              for letter in line.lower() 
              if letter in ascii_lowercase)
```

However, I'm getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` where it highlights `Counter` on the line `print Counter...` and I don't really know why

Comment: You have to indent after `with` statment.

Comment: @Lafada I have done, and it's still giving me the error

Comment: @smitthy - Which version of `python` are you targeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3, [`print` is a function](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function). Therefore, you need to surround its arguments with parentheses when you call it:

```
% python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print 1
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

>>> print(1)
1
```